# How to add another inference in ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

So when I run the code, I'm able to run everything find. When I add another plane's information, and make the for loop display at the end. It brings up the amount of planes I have inputted but it changes all the data back to the latest one.

Example: I create three different airplanes, and once i finish i exit out the loop, but all the information in those 3 airplanes change to the last airplane I put data into.

Do i have to add a counter in the loop for myAl.add();  Or is there another way to do this?

```
public static void Airplane() {

  String choice = "n";  

    ArrayList<Airplane> myAl = new ArrayList();

    do
    {
       Airplane xx = new Airplane();

       // making the airplane
        System.out.println("Please enter the Make of the Airplane:");
       xx.SetMake(myScan.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the Model of the Airplane: ");
       xx.SetModel(myScan.nextLine());
       System.out.println("Please enter the Weight of the Airplane: ");
       xx.SetWeight(Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine()));
       System.out.println("Please enter the Horse Power of the Airplane: ");
       xx.SetHorsePower(Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine()));
        System.out.println("Please enter the Color of the Airplane: ");
        xx.SetColor(myScan.nextLine());
       myAl.add(xx);


        System.out.println("Would you like to add another plane? \n Y/N");
        choice = myScan.nextLine();

    }
    while(!choice.equals("n"));

   Airplane spawn = new Airplane();

   for(int cntr = 0; cntr < myAl.size(); cntr++)
   {
       spawn = myAl.get(cntr);
       System.out.println(spawn.Combine());
   }

}
```

Comment: I could bet that the fields of the `Airplane` class are declared as `static`

Comment: Oh man, thats embarrassing. you are right. Thank you!